# How to validate the products quantity in cart when clicked on proceed to checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

want to make the cart item restriction on the cart page and display the error message when the requirement, not full fill and click on the proceed to checkout button.

Any hook and filter available to check the quantity when the customer clicked on the proceed to checkout.

Let me know if anyone has experience in the woocommerce checkout process.

Comment: check this 
https://wpsuperstar.com/2016/05/22/mastering-woocommerce-hooks-setting-minimum-and-maximum-order-quantities/

Comment: hope it helps ..

Comment: nothing find in this :(

Comment: what you want to do exactly..?Explain it in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use WooCommerce Min/Max Quantities extension to set a minimum and maximum quantity required to checkout.

or

You can set custom code to your functions.php theme file by using "woocommerce_after_checkout_validation" filter and can use $posted array to check value and set validation,

```html
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'rei_after_checkout_validation');

    function rei_after_checkout_validation( $posted ) {

        // do all your logics here...

    }
```

Comment: can woocommerce_after_checkout_validation action call when I clicked on the proceed to checkout button on the cart page?